# Dynamic cast (dynamic_cast) fails with .dylib on OSx (XCode)

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

I'm building an application that consists of a main target and several plugins (dylib's in OSx case).  I started using `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` on this project to cast to and test for specific types in my class hierarchy.  This works well, in general, and is more than fast enough for my application.

My problem is now that sometimes `dynamic_cast` and `dynamic_pointer_cast` would fail in sections of code that were pulled in from the plugins.  I'm using `dlopen` with `RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_LAZY` and I'm also compiling my main target with `--export_dynamic` linker flag, to make sure that all symbols are pulled in. But, still some dynamic casts fail when they should not.

The classes I'm testing with are polymorphic (virtual destructors) and `typeid(...).name()` always returns consistent results. In some cases however, the dynamic casts return null, even though the typeid info seem correct.

The casts seem to always succeed when I compile for debug (no optimisations).

What other linker flags should I use with OSx (XCode, clang), either on the plugins or target to make sure that dynamic casting works correctly in my case?

Comment: You should post a [mcve] exhibiting the problem if you want people to be able to help you.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you. The problem also only presents in my release build. But I will try to put together a clean example.

Comment: You possibly have a One-Definition-Rule violation, and the class you inherit from is not actually the same one you are testing for.  Type identity across loadable modules is not a simple concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the linker settings to make sure dynamic_cast works correctly on OSx when your application also makes use of dynamic libs (.dylib).

My Problem: I shared some code from a lib with more than one dylib and then used dynamic cast to check for and cast from one type to another.  And then in some cases (when compiling under Release) the dynamic_cast(s) would just fail, even though `typeid(..).name()` confirmed that I was working with the correct type.

I tried loading my plugins with `dlopen(.., RTLD_GLOBAL)`, which should allow symbols defined in the dynamic libraries to resolve globally and be made available to other plugins as well. This did not fix my problem, although I did keep it in the code, since it made sense to have it.

I tried adding the `-export_dynamic` linker flag to my application, which should make sure that all global symbols are shared with dynamic libraries when loaded with `dlopen`. Again this did not fix my problem.

Solution:
I finally came across a reference that said that Apple/BSD uses two level symbol name resolution for dynamic libraries, where the library itself is recorded as part of the symbol resolution. This can be switched off with the `-flat_namespace` linker flag.  After I included this flag for all my plugins, everything was working fine.

With the `-flat_namespace` linker flag all my dynamic_casts worked as expected.